# javascript debugger for desktop

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am writing in javascript for windows (and also in wsf using javascript and vbscript) a desktop script not for internet and not using any explorer. 
I need tool for debugging (free one).

Does someone can recommend on one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are creating WSH scripts based on your description. In order to debug WSH JavaScripts, start your script with **wscript.exe /d *path to WSH file*** after that, whenever an exception is going to occur, you are going to be presented with a choice to debug the script with Visual Studio or Microsoft Script Debugger (free). If you just want to step through the code start your script with **wscript.exe /d /x *path to WSH file*** this will cause an exception right at the begging of your script execution.
More information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308364)

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) is a great Eclipse extension and can also debug Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I've heard Firebug Lite could do this? That's probably not what you're looking for still.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it sounds like you are trying to make an AJAX app that perhaps loads from local javascript + HTML.

That said, if it is OK to use Firefox as the web client, you might try Firebug.  It is an excellent javascript debugger.  It lets you do usual step / breakpoint things, inspect variables, and display the current page as a DOM model to help see what your jQuery (or Prototype, in my case) queries will find.

Comment: No, he's writing for the local Windows desktop environment.